# Как поставить лимит на количество сообщений от пользователя в telethon (python)?

Tags: python, telethon

У меня есть бот на telethon, где пользователю для аутентификации необходимо ввести код подтверждения. Я хочу ограничить кол-во попыток введения кода, подскажите пожалуйста куда копать, чтобы подобное сделать? Знаю, что в aiogram при помощи current_state можно прям повесить на чат кол-во попыток, но не знаю, как это сделать в telethon